# Unable to authorize for google cloud function with oauth token obtained with App Script app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-cloud-functions

Basically, I'm trying to use the login/credentials obtained through the oauth2 flow of a google sheets App Script app, and for whatever reason, they are not working.

The workflow of my app that I am trying is:

1. Grant the app permissions upon starting
2. use `ScriptApp.getIdentityToken()` to obtain the identity token
3. Use that identity token to call a google cloud function

```
  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "payload": JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getIdentityToken()}` // this is how I saw many others online doing it as well
    }
  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

Are there issues with using tokens like this, such as passing them around? If so, can I use the identity token to obtain a new token to invoke the function with?

Are there any workarounds to this?

Here's what I've tried:

1. I've verified that the cloud function is able to be called with a valid id token (obtained through the gcloud cli) for the same email
2. I've verified via queries to https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo that the tokens I'm obtaining in my app script are valid tokens for the same email (well valid in the sense that they decode, clearly they are for some reason invalid)
3. I've verified that I'm using an idToken and not accessToken
4. I've certified that the tokens still don't work in postman, so I don't believe it's an app script problem
5. I've tried the oauth flow through the app itself, specifying scopes in the manifest:

```
    "openid",
    "<avoiding stackoverflow spam filter>/auth/script.external_request",
    "<avoiding stackoverflow spam filter>/auth/userinfo.email",
    "<avoiding stackoverflow spam filter>/auth/cloud-platform",
    ...
```

5. I have tried the oauth flow through the official oauth2 library

```
OAuth2.createService('Google')

      ...

      .setScope('<scopes, but can't list due to stack overflow spam filter>')
      .setParam('login_hint', Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail())
      .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
      .setParam('prompt', 'consent');
```

When I try to invoke the function with the app script token as the authorization:

```
401
Error: Unauthorized
Your client does not have permission to the requested URL /<my function name>.
```

But I know that the client does in fact have permission since the email has not only cloud invocation permissions, but is the owner of the function.

Comment: I wrote that article. It should help you: https://medium.com/google-cloud/call-cloud-run-from-app-script-the-easy-way-70677086efa1

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I actually haven't seen that article yet, but it looks like a great strategy. I'll give it a try thanks

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere so I can successfully call the cloud function now, but I guess part of the problem now is that the user is not the one authorized to call the function. I am looking to use the same oauth token used to call the cloud function to call the spreadsheets api inside of the function. Is this possible?

Comment: No, it isn't. Google Cloud does not allow to reuse user credential for subsequent calls (for security reason)